# GitHub Pages Jekyll won't build

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to add a new post to a blog using Jekyll and Github Pages (Untouched since 08/2015)

However even though the Travis build passes, the Github Pages build fails without a single error message
[image]

I'm guessing it's about some outdated plugins, but I've got no idea what is it

// _config.yml
[image]

// Gemfile
[image]

Here's the repository:
https://github.com/wende/wende.github.io/

Comment: As of August 23, 2016, Github is using Jekyll 3.2 as described in [this post](https://github.com/blog/2220-github-pages-to-upgrade-to-jekyll-3-2). My guess is that if your last build was in August 2015 you were using an earlier version of Jekyll (the Gemfile.lock file in your repo says 3.1.6). If you upgrade your version of Jekyll does your site still build locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out Github Pages use Jekyll 3.2.1 now. Which requires `.config.yml`"theme" property to be empty.

Changing theme to theme_settings and all references to it fixed the issue